# Extjs : clear selections in item selector

Tags: extjs, itemselector

What I have is I have an item selector with available users and assigned users as two different columns. On clicking any user in the available users and clicking a different menu option, the selected user from the available users columns is still displayed. How do I clear the selection upon clicking a different menu ?

Here's how the screen looks with the selection under a particular menu :

[image]

And here's the selection again after opting a different menu : [image]

I tried, accessing the store and clearValue() and setValue('') which is not right solution and I was not able to access the selecitonModel to perform clearSelections() here.

How do I clear the selections upon clicking menu?

Would greatly appreciate your help, thanks a lot.

Comment: can you share the code or fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getSelectionModel().deselectAll()` method of the "Users View"  (that you want to clear the selection) within the listener `select` from the "Roles View". This will cause all user record selections to be removed when selecting a different menu. See docs: [getSelectionModel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.view.View.html#method-getSelectionModel), [deselectAll](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.selection.DataViewModel.html#method-deselectAll).

Example:

```
{
    xtype: 'dataview',
    .
    .
    .

    listeners: {
        select: function(dataview, record, index, eOpts){
            dataview.view.up('viewport').down('#usersView').getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Within the listener, it performs the method to deselect all records from the target view.

These methods are commonly found in components that have the selection behavior, such as the `grid`.

See this fiddle: [Deselect DataView Items](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2na6).

Answer (score 0):

```
store.removeAll();
```

is this what you are looking for